# What lifecycle methods called when the activity home button is pressed if you in one activity?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle, android-navigation, android-homebutton

I thought when we press home button where ever you are your onPause() and onStop() will be called. But I'm not completely sure. Please give me some more info.

Comment: onPause() is called when Home button is pressed. Also, home button can't be overrided. It just sends all the applications to the background and opens the main screen of phone.

Comment: Is our activity is stoped when we press home button?

Comment: It won't stop. Home will just call onPause as it is sending app to background. It depends on the onPause function of app.

Comment: No Onpause and OnStop Both are calling just now i tried the sample.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, you press the home button **onpause** and **onStop** is called. **But** if your activity has parameter's like **android:noHistory="true"** it will cause your activity's  **onDestroy** to be called. Though I am not sure there may be similar scenario's for properties in **android:launchMode**.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the main difference between onPause and onStop is that onPause is called when the activity about to enter the stage where it is partially obscured.(onStop - fully obscured) When you click your home button, you are about to enter a stage where the activity is fully obscured. But to enter that stage, you would have had to already gone through the stage where the activity is partially obscured(why onPause is also called). Thats why onPause is always called before onStop. (transition from partially obscured to fully obscured)

Comment: Okay then both two methods are executed right.I told the same thing. But @berserk told it is not stoped. So i didn't get clarity.

Comment: it will stop. override it and do a log.d inside the onstop to see if its called(will be)

Comment: I just gave an answer that i think would be more satisfying